# How to get a large amount of data in wcf without setting max buffer size

Tags: c#, wcf

I have one question about wcf - I want to get large amount of data using wcf service, but I don't want to change config file.

For example - if data is over buffersize or maxReceivedMessageSize I want to split it into packs and send it one by one. On Client side I want to get all of packs and recreate final response.

It is possible?

Comment: have you tried it? do you get any error? i think wcf takes cares of that for you i.e splitting and recreation

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is built-in support for that in WCF. You will have to come up with you own way of splitting data on the server side and combining it on the client side. And you will have to make multiple calls to transfer all data. It's probably a good idea anyway since you might want to show progress bar or something if you transfer a lot of data.

UPDATE:
After some googling I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717050.aspx). Essentially you can create you custom channel that would do chunking for you. Still, I would probably implement chunking on the application level rather than channel level.

Comment: That's sad, there is no built-in support, but thank You for very fast answer!

Comment: Fast doesn't mean good :). After some googling I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717050.aspx. Essentially you can create you custom channel that would do chunking for you. Still, I would probably implement chunking on the application level rather than channel level.